How to prevent a regression model from overpredicting lower values and underpredicting higher ones
I'm trying to predict rental prices for houses that are listed for sale. My training set consists of houses that are listed for rent. With the predictions, my idea is to then compute an estimate of profitability (rental price/sale price).
The problem I'm having is that any regression model tends to overestimate the rental price of cheap places, and underestimate that of expensive places. As a result, the profitability of cheap listings is inflated, and that of expensive listings is underestimated.
It's the expected behavior: the baseline prediction is the mean/median of my target, and as I add more features, the predictions deviate from that, but not enough to get rid of this bias. However, it's very problematic for my business problem.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this bias?

Probably you simply lacks good predictors, can you get better ones?

This is why “regression” has its name, because of regression to the mean.

It could also be because you are trying to do a linear regression, but your relationship between the outcome variable and the predictors is not linear. Can you try including higher order terms in your regression? Or maybe interaction terms? To best identify possible non-linearities, try graphing your data (even if it is 1 predictor at a time).

Not sure this quite qualifies as a duplicate (and I'm not willing to cast a unilateral duplicate vote), but I stand by my comment there about who wants ice water.
